# Single useSelector instead of multiple useSelector

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-hooks

> I am working on React web app using typescript, hooks. Each component
> must have only one useSelector(), but actually I have 2 useSelector(),
> Is there any solution for 2 useSelector() to be merged or something
> else.

```
export default function UserInfo() {
    const { city1, city2, city3 } = useSelector(cityNameSelector);
    const { country } = useSelector(countryNameSelector);
.....
...
}
```

Comment: You may call useSelector() multiple times within a single function component. Each call to useSelector() creates an individual subscription to the Redux store. Because of the React update batching behavior used in React Redux v7, a dispatched action that causes multiple useSelector()s in the same component to return new values should only result in a single re-render. - https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector

Comment: can we avoid useSelector and can be done by direct import

Comment: No, because `useSelector()` causes the component to re-render when the state changes. You should read `react-redux` docs.